# How do I update my UI without stuttering / deadlocks

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, asynchronous, mvvm

I have a WPF application which has a `DataGrid` that is bound to to a `ObservableCollection<string>` named *"Customers"* and I also have a button which is bound to a command which starts a some what heavy task. it simulates adding a bunch of entries to the `DataGrid`as fast as possible.

The issue I am facing is that while it's adding entries to the `DataGrid` there appears to be stutters and some times deadlocks when trying to move the UI as it's adding entries to the `DataGrid`.

From my understanding it's because I am updating the `DataGrid` on the UI thread using `Application.Current.Dispatcher.Invoke(() => { /*Update OC*/ });`
and even tho they might be *small updates* to the UI, a lot of them might cause stuttering, now that's my understanding and I might be completely wrong.

My question is.. Is there a way to make this async or reduce the stuttering / deadlocks some other way?

XAML UI

```
<Window.DataContext>
    <local:MainViewModel/>
</Window.DataContext>

<Grid>
    <StackPanel>
        <DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding Customers}" AutoGenerateColumns="False" 
                  Width="300" Height="200">
            <DataGrid.Columns>
                <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Image" Width="SizeToCells" IsReadOnly="True">
                    <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding }" />
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn>
            </DataGrid.Columns>
        </DataGrid>
        <Button Width="100"
                Height="25"
                Content="Start"
                Command="{Binding StartAddingCommand}"/>
    </StackPanel>

    <Border VerticalAlignment="Bottom"
            Height="25" Background="Orange">
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Customers.Count}"
                   HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
    </Border>
</Grid>
```

MainViewModel

```
class MainViewModel : ObservableObject
    {
        public ObservableCollection<string> Customers { get; set; }
        public RelayCommand StartAddingCommand { get; set; }
        public MainViewModel()
        {
            Customers = new ObservableCollection<string>();
            StartAddingCommand = new RelayCommand(o => AddCustomers(), o => true);
        }


        private void AddCustomers()
        {
            Task.Run(() =>
            {
                try
                {
                    foreach (var VARIABLE in GetHTML("https://pastebin.com/raw/gG540TEj"))
                    {
                        Application.Current.Dispatcher.Invoke(() =>
                        {
                            Customers.Add(VARIABLE.ToString());
                        });
                    }
                }
                catch (Exception e)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(e);
                    throw;
                }

            });

        }


        public string GetHTML(string page)
        {
            WebClient client = new WebClient();
            return client.DownloadString(page);
        }
    }
```

And the RelayCommand & ObservableObject are just generic ones.

RelayCommand

```
public class RelayCommand : ICommand
    {
        private Action<object> execute;
        private Func<object, bool> canExecute;

        public event EventHandler CanExecuteChanged
        {
            add { CommandManager.RequerySuggested += value; }
            remove { CommandManager.RequerySuggested -= value; }
        }

        public RelayCommand(Action<object> execute, Func<object, bool> canExecute = null)
        {
            this.execute = execute;
            this.canExecute = canExecute;
        }

        public bool CanExecute(object parameter)
        {
            return this.canExecute == null || this.canExecute(parameter);
        }

        public void Execute(object parameter)
        {
            this.execute(parameter);
        }
    }
```

ObservableObject

```
class ObservableObject : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    [NotifyPropertyChangedInvocator]
    protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
}
```

Comment: There's an overhead per add you're doing. Usually, I'd go get the data in a task and return the results to the UI thread then add the lot rather than invoke per entry.  Would that not suit?  Also. You can use invokeasync with dispatcherpriority.contextidle to reduce the priority so the ui is more responsive.

Answer (score 0):

Doing a `foreach` with `Dispatcher.Invoke` without any delay will of course block the UI.

You should definitely have an `async` version of your `GetHTML` method and write the `AddCustomers` like shown below. Use for example one of the `Get...Async` methods of the `HttpClient` class.

```
private async Task AddCustomers()
{
    try
    {
        foreach (var result in await GetHTMLAsync("https://pastebin.com/raw/gG540TEj"))
        {
            Customers.Add(result.ToString());
        }
     }
     catch (Exception e)
     {
         Debug.WriteLine(e);
         throw;
     }
}
```

Then await the method in the command action:

```
StartAddingCommand = new RelayCommand(async o => await AddCustomers(), o => true);
```